# Tapestry Prototype selecting element by ID on zone updates

Tags: java, javascript, prototypejs, tapestry, zone

I have a zone on my page that contains a select element.

I'm adding an `onChange` listener on that element via JavaScript (thanks to http://jsfiddle.net/AnbmU/6/)

```
void afterRender() {
    javaScriptSupport.addScript(
        "$('groupSelecter').observe('change', function() {" + 
        "    var width = $(this).getWidth();" + 
        "    var selectBox = $('groupSelecter');" + 
        "    var chosen = selectBox.selectedIndex >= 0 ? selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].innerHTML : undefined;" + 
        "    $(this).next('.ninja-input')" + 
        "         .toggleClassName('hidden', chosen != 'Create New Group...')" + 
        "         .select();" + 
        "});",
        ""
    );
}
```

The problem occurs when I trigger a zone refresh, my select changes `id` to something like this: `groupSelecter_846e54edd0b5`.

Is there a way to either keep the select's element id constant or to be able to change javascript and select's id on each zone update?

EDIT:
Another issue I was not aware of before.

Hidden input field is toggled each second change of selected elements, regardless of its contents. For example, if I had `GROUP_1`, `GROUP_2`, `GROUP_3` and `Create New Group...` and `GROUP_1` initially selected, and changed to `GROUP_2`, the input box appears. When I change it to `Create New Group...`, the input is hidden again. Again, when I change to `GROUP_3`, the input field appears. Mind you, in JSfiddle, this works just fine. But for some reason, it doesn't work in my Tapestry project.

EDIT2:
OK, I tried some more fiddling:

Tapestry generated select element with `id=groupSelecter_d769af562f89`.
It also generated inserted this JavaScript (on the bottom of HTML):

```
$$('.groupSelecter').invoke('observe', 'change', function() {
    var width = $(this).getWidth();
    var chosen = $(this).selectedIndex >= 0 ? $(this).options[$(this).selectedIndex].innerHTML : undefined;
    $(this).next('.ninja-input')
        .toggleClassName('ninja-hidden', chosen != 'Create New Group...');
});
```

I inpected the element in Firefox, navigated to  tags, found the generated code and cut it out. After that, I opened firefox JS console and pasted that same exact code I just cut. And, voila, it works, for some reason. (Class selecting, that is).

Comment: Apparently, PrototypeJS 1.6.1.0 does not have a method `Element.toggleClassName(element, className[, bool])`, but only `Element.toggleClassName(element, className)`, which was causing my error in EDIT2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you fire the javascript every time the select renders. You are currently only firing it on page render (not ajax update).

You could either do it in a [mixin](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-mixins.html), or you could add the script during page render AND ajax update. If you use a class attribute or data attribute (as suggested in other answers on this thread) you can just add the script via JavaScriptSupport in both events since the value is known before the select component renders.

If you want to use the clientId in the ajax action this is slightly tricky because you can only add the script after the select component has rendered. Before this time the clientId will not be defined. If you want to do this I suggest returning a [RenderCommand](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/runtime/RenderCommand.html) from your ajax action. Note that [Block](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/Block.html) can be [TypeCoerced](http://tapestry.apache.org/typecoercer-service.html) to RenderCommand

eg:

```
@InjectComponent
private Zone zone;

@InjectComponent
private Select groupSelector;

@Inject
private TypeCoercer typeCoercer;

RenderCommand onActionFromSomeComponent() {
    return new RenderCommand() {
        public void render(MarkupWriter writer, RenderQueue queue) {
            RenderCommand zoneBody = typeCoercer.coerce(zone.getBody(), RenderCommand.class);
            zoneBody.render(writer, queue);
            javaScriptSupport.addScript(
                "$('%s').observe('change', function() {" + 
                   // more stuff
                 "});",
                 groupSelector.getClientId()
            );
        }
    };
}

void afterRender() {
    javaScriptSupport.addScript(
        "$('%s').observe('change', function() {" + 
            // more stuff
        "});",
        groupSelector.getClientId()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Tapestry but if it doesn't change the class attributes you can attach to a class

instead of

```
$('groupSelecter').observe('change', function() {
```

you add a class of the same name 'groupSelector'

```
$$('.groupSelector').first().observe('change',function() {
```

or if you have multiple elements

```
$$('.groupSelector').invoke('observe','change',function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that [Geek Num 88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341491/geek-num-88)'s idea of adding a class and selecting by that class doesn't work. You could also add a data-* attribute and select by that.

Otherwise, you could observe the dynamic clientId.

```
@InjectComponent
private Select groupSelector;

void afterRender() {
    javaScriptSupport.addScript(
        "$('%s').observe('change', function() {" + 
            // more stuff
        "});",
    groupSelector.getClientId());
}
```

BTW. The tapestry way of solving this is to move your script to a js file and use T5.extendInitializers(...), JavaScriptSupport.addInitializerCall(...) and @Import. Demo [here](http://tapestry-stitch.uklance.cloudbees.net/oneventdemo)

Comment: The funniest thing is that on jsfiddle, it works just fine, but in Tapestry, not so good.

Comment: Also, I did try to use `groupSelector.getCliendID();`, but to no avail. It does not return the suffixed, generated ID.

Comment: Where is your ```afterRender()``` method? If it's on your page, it will only be called when the page renders, not on ajax update.

Comment: Yes, I have my `afterRender()` method on my `Page.java`.

Comment: So, the listener is only attached to the select when the page first renders. After zone update, the new select does not have a change listener.

Comment: Well, you need to execute the script every time the component renders. A mixin is one option, another is to execute the script during page render AND in your ajax action.

Comment: When you say "in your ajax action", what exactly do you mean? Like a `onActionFromSomeComponent` method and then add JSCallback or something else?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include adding adding JSCallback via ajaxResponseRenderer so I can accept it :)